# error with my connection in java to a Postgres database

Tags: java, postgresql

I try to connect with a database of Postgres postgresql-9.1-902.jdbc4 in Netbeans 7.0 and I get this error in Java :

```
jul 19, 2012 9:35:02 AM databasedesktop.DatabaseDesktopApp startup
Grave: null
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: El intento de conexión falló.
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:150)
    at org.postgresql.core.ConnectionFactory.openConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:64)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Connection.<init>(AbstractJdbc2Connection.java:123)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc3.AbstractJdbc3Connection.<init>(AbstractJdbc3Connection.java:28)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc3g.AbstractJdbc3gConnection.<init>(AbstractJdbc3gConnection.java:20)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc4.AbstractJdbc4Connection.<init>(AbstractJdbc4Connection.java:30)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc4.Jdbc4Connection.<init>(Jdbc4Connection.java:22)
    at org.postgresql.Driver.makeConnection(Driver.java:391)
    at org.postgresql.Driver.connect(Driver.java:265)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:579)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:221)
    at databasedesktop.DatabaseDesktop.initDatabasePostgre(DatabaseDesktop.java:45)
    at databasedesktop.DatabaseDesktop.<init>(DatabaseDesktop.java:56)
    at databasedesktop.DatabaseDesktopApp.startup(DatabaseDesktopApp.java:22)
    at org.jdesktop.application.Application$1.run(Application.java:171)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:251)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:705)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$000(EventQueue.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:666)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:664)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:675)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:211)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:128)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:117)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:113)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:90)
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Can't connect to SOCKS proxy:No route to host: connect
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:427)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:578)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:527)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:424)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:207)
    at org.postgresql.core.PGStream.<init>(PGStream.java:60)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:74)
    ... 28 more
```

Comment: is your postgres instance running?

Comment: Can you connect to your database with [pgadmin](http://www.pgadmin.org/)?

Comment: Yes my instance of postgres in running

Comment: yes i connect to database good

Comment: @viktor: Have you abandoned this question? Found a solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You appear to be trying to use a `SOCKS` proxy that is not running or reachable.

```
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Can't connect to SOCKS proxy:No route to host: connect
```

Make sure that the proxy is actually running, and that it can reach the PostgreSQL server. Try using `psql` to connect to the PostgreSQL server via your SOCKS proxy to verify that works - assuming you intended to connect via the proxy.

Have you set the `socksProxyHost` and `socksProxyPort` system properties, perhaps via the java command line? See [this Java documentation on proxies](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/net/proxies.html).

Are you specifying a proxy to your JDBC connection?

Comment: I try to connect to a database first locally and i get the same error and to other machine i get the same

Comment: @viktor I don't really understand what you just said there, sorry. It still sounds like a configuration problem with your Java runtime or your connection string. Please update your question with (a) a dump of your system properties from the `System.getProperties()` call (iterate through them and print them to `System.out`) and (b) your JDBC connection string or properties map.

Comment: @viktor Are you intentionally using a SOCKS proxy, by the way? Is the proxy set up on purpose?